# R Script for Computing Image Means and Raster Value Subtractions

Tags: r, digital-image-processing, postgis-raster

I have a very specific script I am trying to make which computes image flatfields. Basically, I am computing a Master Dark Frame (MD) by averaging a set of Dark Photos.

I have a set of light photos as well. I want to take the averaged dark photo and subtract that average from each light photo within a directory. After this, a Master Flat (MF) is made by averaging all the light photos which had been subject to dark frame subtractions.

Here is my script so far:

```
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
##Takes all dark frame images from within working directory and stacks them   into a single object 
darkrastdat<- list.files()
darkstack<- stack(darkrastdat)
##computes the mean of all dark layers/pixels within the object, omits no- data values 
masterdark <- mean(darkstack, na.rm=TRUE)

##loads each light frame into an object 
lightrastdat<- list.files()

##subtracts master dark from each light frame 

##stacks and averages light frames 

##writes master flat as 16-bit into original working directory
writeRaster(mrast, filename= "MF.tif", datatype='INT2U', overwrite=TRUE)
```

I am able to get an master dark frame (MD) from within a directory of photos. I am having trouble coming up with a way to subtract that MD from each light frame individually.

Can anyone give me some advice?

Comment: Are you just trying to subtract one raster from another? `r3 = r2 - r1` works if `r1` etc are raster objects.

Comment: Hey Spacedman - I want to do just that - but I'd like to subract one raster from 20 files in a directory. i.e the Raster1 - MasterFlat1, Raster2-MasterFlat1, Raster3-MasterFlat1, Raster4-MasterFlat1, etc.

Comment: Do you know how to write loops in R? Loop over the raster files, read each one in, subtract your masterflat, save it (or whatever).

Comment: That's exactly what I am having issues with actually  - is writing the loop for it. I haven't had much experience with loops for loading files in within a directory and assigning each a unique object.... quite tricky! haha

Comment: something like `allrasters = lapply(list.files(), function(f){raster(f)})` or a `for` loop...

Comment: okay this is my horrible attempt (don't laugh) - I am learning R on the fly here, and asides from stats functions am a beginner: `lightrastdat<- list.files()
for (i in lightrastdat){
  s= lightrastdat - masterdark
}`

Comment: sorry its not displaying the lines and indenting properly but you get the point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want to do something like this:

```
lightrastdat<- list.files()
corrected_rasters = lapply(
   lightrastdat, 
   function(file){
     r = raster(file)
     return(r - masterdark)
   }
)

# this is how you do mean(r[[1]], r[[2]], r[[3]],... etc) when you don't 
# know how many rasters are in your list:

corrected_mean = do.call(mean, corrected_rasters)
```

Then save `corrected_mean` as a raster file.

The `lapply` gets the file names and for each one applies a function that reads in a raster from that file and subtracts the correction. The end result of `lapply` here is a list of raster objects.

To compute the mean of a list of objects, you need to use `do.call`, which applies a function as if the second argument to `do.call` was in the arguments. This lets you do `foo(a[[1]],a[[2]],a[[3]],...)` up to however many things are in `a`.

Comment: Thanks Spacedman- looks like this does just what I was wanting to do. And looks like I learned a thing or two about the lapply function and do.call - which are definitely extremely valuable. I should be able to adapt these into some other variations of scripts I have in mind. Thanks so much!